# Where is the Software Centre in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, software-center

This has been apparent since my upgrade to 12.04. Just wondering if theres a way to manually open the software center or locate it?

Comment: Is it not on the launcher?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 10):

### Some ways to start the Software Center from the desktop

#### 1. From the Launcher

[image]

#### 2. From the Dash

- Click the Ubuntu icon on the top left or press the Windows/Super key and type: `software`:

  [image]

#### 3. How to bring it back to the launcher

If Software Center is not on your launcher as shown in section 1 above, just start it, and then right-click on its icon in the launcher and click on "Lock to Launcher":

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Issue this from commandline and software center should show up (or throw an error)

```
/usr/bin/software-center
```

After it opens pin it to the launcher for easy access.